# Lambda for getter and setter of property

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

In C# 6.0 I can write:

```
public int Prop => 777;
```

But I want to use getter and setter.
Is there a way to do something kind of the next?

```
public int Prop {
   get => propVar;
   set => propVar = value;
}
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? This only makes sense to me if you don't add any more complicated logic than simply loading/storing the value from/to a field, at which point auto-implemented properties would already cover your need. What type of implementation do you have in mind that is so short that the `=>` syntax is worth it, but yet too complicated for auto-implemented properties?

Comment: Why don't you use an auto property?

Comment: It's not uncommon to need to map a property to something else, when implementing an interface for example. The expression body style just keeps things compact.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

First of all, that is not lambda, although syntax is similar.

It is called "[expression-bodied members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)". They are similar to lambdas, but still fundamentally different. Obviously they can't capture local variables like lambdas do. Also, unlike lambdas, they are accessible via their name:) You will probably understand this better if you try to pass an expression-bodied property as a delegate.

There is no such syntax for setters in C# 6.0, but [C# 7.0 introduces it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#property-set-statements).

```
private int _x;
public int X
{
    get => _x;
    set => _x = value;
}
```

Comment: If you use the 6.0 syntax (public X => _x) will that still be recognized in 7.0? i.e. that you're specifying the getter even though you don't say it explicitly?

Comment: you forgot the in int public X

Comment: @KevinVictor yes, it will be recognized and treated as a readonly property

Comment: Something else worth mentioning is you can assign the value directly in the getter if it's not already. get => _value ?? (_value = InitializeValue());

Answer (score 55):

[C# 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/) brings support for setters, amongst other members:

> ## More expression bodied members
>
> Expression bodied methods, properties etc. are a big hit in C# 6.0,
>   but we didn’t allow them in all kinds of members. C# 7.0 adds
>   accessors, constructors and finalizers to the list of things that can
>   have expression bodies:
>
> ```
> class Person
> {
>     private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> names = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
>     private int id = GetId();
>
>     public Person(string name) => names.TryAdd(id, name); // constructors
>     ~Person() => names.TryRemove(id, out _);              // finalizers
>     public string Name
>     {
>         get => names[id];                                 // getters
>         set => names[id] = value;                         // setters
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: @Achilles1515 thanks for the edit, the source snippet was updated to correct this after I posted the answer. I also updated the out variable name to match the current version of the source snippet.

Comment: For more visit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#properties

Answer (score -4):

As of C#6 there was no such syntax, but the older syntax is pretty similar:

```
    private int propVar;
    public int Prop 
    {
        get { return propVar; }
        set { propVar = value; }
    }
```

Or

```
public int Prop { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is demonstrably not true, as the answers above indicate.

Comment: Did he mean no such syntax for setters in C# 6.0 ?

Comment: It is a pretty old topic, but this is what I meant ;)

Comment: hint @MarcinIwanowski, if you delete the answer I think you'll get rid of the negative reputation. ;) Just a thought.

Comment: @PerLundberg it is funny to see that 7 years later still there is someone who read my answer. And still - my answer is correct so there is no reason to delete it. Negative repution, on stackoverflow? Who cares?

Comment: Yeah, the Internet never forgets. :-) It's of course up to you. I _think_ that the reason why it got downvoted was that it _is_ supported for getters even in C# 6.0 (but not for setters). But the distinction between what was supported in C# 6.0 and 7.0 is hopefully largely irrelevant by now. :P

Comment: And the reality is that this syntax is explicit and readable and understandable for everyone. Not just people who only know the latest version of one language.